# cakephp saveField decrement or alternative

Tags: sql-update, relationship, cakephp-2.3

I have a controller action on (for example) a Model called Message. This is very simple and allows the system to record a message sent about a booking (model is called Booking). The controller sends an email and records the content of the email to the message table. Once it's done that I need to decrement the amount of available bookings.

```
$this->loadModel('Booking');                
$this->Booking->id = $bookingID;
$this->Booking->saveField('booking_allotment', 'booking_allotment - 1');
```

The code above is what I have so far, but it doesn't work. Rather than decrement the allotment, it sets it to 0. If I hard code a number it will update with that hard coded number.

This question has two parts to it really. Firstly this solution I have from my reading of the docs and research is more complicated than I need. I understand that by including...

```
$this->loadModel('Booking');
```

...I will be running all the relationships between the table that I don't need as well as it simply not working.

If I was not using cake, the UPDATE query would be extremely simple. Is there a simpler alternative that will work, or if not, can anyone help me achieve what I need to do? I am using cakePHP 2.3

Comment: If you understand that you are ruining your relations - why are you doing it then?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with `'booking_allotment - 1'`? Are you trying to decrement the value that is set in the booking_allotment field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I was not using cake, the UPDATE query would be extremely simple.

It's even simpler using CakePHP... CakePHP is not the problem. Your problem is (really) "a piece of cake". You want to decrement an integer value for the available bookings but you are trying to store a string in your table field:

> $this->Booking->saveField('booking_allotment', **'booking_allotment - 1'**);

I guess that the "0" value is automatically stored due to an unstorable type problem. You should really validate your fields using the Model $validate variable.

Second, the loadModel call is ALWAYS to avoid: the 90% of the times it's used for solving problem caused by a wrong problem-analysis. For example, here's what I'm guessing by your particular case...

You should have:

```
1. a "Package" model for all the available offers (Package hasMany Booking / AvailableBooking)
2. a "Booking" model for all the user's bookings (Booking belongs to Package / hasMany Message)
3. a "AvailableBooking" model for the available Booking number for the current month/week/anything-else (dependent on your customer's needs)
4. a "Message" model for your Booking communications
```

Defining your relationships between models you should access from other controllers with this statement (for example):

```
$this->Package->Booking->find();
$this->Package->Booking->Message->find();
$this->Message->Booking->find();
```

I really suggest you to read the CookBook paying much more attention (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html).

Let's finish this post solving your problem...

```
1. Set the Booking id as you did...
2. Read the field that contains the value you're searching for... and decrement it
3. Save the decremented field value

$this->Booking->id = $id;
$this->Booking->saveField('your_field', $this->Booking->field('your_field') - 1);
```

Happy Coding!